# json File error: Expected Identifier or '('

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am using some json files that are saved into my Xcode project. But I cannot access them as I keep getting the error "Expected Identifier or '('". I have validated the file in jonlint.com
I am using the following method to access teh said json file

```
NSString *fileName = @"airportlist.json";
NSURL *documentsFolderURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsFolderURL.path stringByAppendingString:fileName];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *jsonError;
_jsonOfAirPorts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a compiler error? You may want to edit your question to be more specific and include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: will u please post ur json file ?

Comment: I cant post it here, I am sorry. But I have successfully validated it in jsonlint.com

Comment: You should post a minimal example that can be compiled and exhibits the problem. The code fragment you posted isn't very useful by itself nor is your description of the problem. Where is the error occurring? Are you getting a compilation error or is the problem in the runtime?

Comment: Its a compilation error. The Build Fails

Comment: You probably forgot to close a bracket somewhere.

Comment: Well are you getting a compiler error or runtime error? It clearly looks like the former, in which case XCode will tell you exactly where to look and we cannot help you unless you post the relevant code.

Also you should try it with another json file, just to be sure it's not the problem.

In general, always do your own research before asking here.

Comment: If that was the case, it wouldn't have been validated successfully, right?

Comment: I don't think the problem is your JSON file. An invalid JSON file would more likely cause a runtime error. One of your source files is probably missing a closing bracket. Without any more source code or the full error message, we can't pin down the error any further.

Comment: will u please show your json file contents ?

Comment: @poojathorat sorry I cant do that. its not allowed for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing json file contents using this

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airportlist" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Comment: @SidharthJDev I'm glad you managed to fix the issue but for the benefit of future readers, I'll put on the record that usually, this kind of error is a syntax error in one of the source files rather than with the way you accessed the JSON file. Future readers should double check they haven't missed a closing bracket before rewriting chunks of code.